# Unable to get 'Fling' working for up and down flings

Tags: java, android

I am currently making a sliding puzzle game, which uses the fling gesture to move the tiles.

I have the following method which works for left/right however does not seem to work for up and down:

```
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (velocityX > 10.0f) {
                FlingRight((ImageView) mView);
            } else if (velocityX < -10.0f) {
                FlingLeft((ImageView) mView);
            } else if (velocityY > 10.0f) {
                FlingUp((ImageView) mView);
            } else if (velocityY < -10.0f) {
                FlingDown((ImageView) mView);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Log.i("Fling", "Fling error: " + e.toString()); }
        return true;
    }
```

The logcat error is:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```
>
> at mobile.labs.acw.Game.FlingLeft(Game.java:100)

It shouldn't be calling FlingLeft however.

And when putting a break point in the FlingUp and FlingDown methods it seems they are never hit.

Comment: I would assume that when you are flinging up/down you are also flinging left a bit. So while your velocityY is maybe 200 your velocityX is still < -10.0f and therefore you always just hit FlingLeft. Solution is to check for the largest value and see if that value is higher than a threshhold.

Comment: Thank you I didn't think of that! Great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben's suggestion, the following solved the issue:

```
if (Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)){
                    if (velocityX > 10.0f) {
                        FlingRight((ImageView) mView);
                    } else if (velocityX < -10.0f) {
                        FlingLeft((ImageView) mView);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (velocityY > 10.0f) {
                        FlingUp((ImageView) mView);
                    } else if (velocityY < -10.0f) {
                        FlingDown((ImageView) mView);
                    }
                }
```